# How to update Elasticsearch index on change in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, django, elasticsearch, django-orm

I am working on django project. I am performing queries from my database and updating the elasticsearch index at regular intervals based on the timestamps in database. Like if the timestamp is within last hour then I query those objects and add it to the ES index.

But I am facing few issues in this process.

1. In django we perform .update() to update the existing object in database but this is not changing the timestamp and hence it is not coming in query and I cant update the ES index.
2. Also if I delete an object in database using query I cant check the deleted objects and then I cannot update the index.

Can anyone suggest me to solve these issues or any other way to update the index.

Comment: some questions: (1) what DB is it? (2) who is responsible for keeping the DB and Elasticsearch in sync? the same django project or a separated software? (3) can you change the schema of the db?

Comment: @glenacota using MySQL db. I am using crontab in django that queries the changes from MySQL based update timestamp for Last half hour and then create or update the index in elasticsearch. Can do minor schema change in db.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a message queue like Kafka with a CDC tool like [Maxwell](https://maxwells-daemon.io/)? Maxwell will monitor your MySQL *binlogs* and throw changes caused by DML commands to different topics in your queue. You can have a single topic for each of your table, then write consumption logic (in your case syncing the ES index with MySQL db)

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: NO, I am not affiliated to any service that I have mentioned in the answer, we might as well use open source tools like RabbitMQ. It's just that at my place of work, I've used Kafka